# How to run application in background mode forever?

Tags: core-location, cllocationmanager

i got one critical problem let me share with you .
i have an iphone app that need to send current location to server whether app is on background mode or foreground mode per minute.
i done setting property in info.plist parameter like background mode-->location and other code for location configuration is usual

```
- (CLLocationManager *)loc_mngr {

    if (loc_mngr != nil) {
        return loc_mngr;
    }


    loc_mngr = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    loc_mngr.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;
    loc_mngr.delegate = self;
    return loc_mngr;

}
```

loc_mngr is an object of CLLocationManager.
delegate method implementation is done.
it work for me but the problem is how to handel location service enable when my app is on background.
please help me how to deal with it?
thanks in adv.

Comment: sorry but i dont understand your comment in terms of what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [this apple document](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html), you are having following methods to do this thing.

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(0.0, 0.0); 
CLRegion *region = [[CLRegion alloc] initWithCircularRegionWithCenter:coord radius:500 identifier:@"Some Identifier"];
```

And then, register the region with the framework:

```
[locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:region];
```

The delegate protocols define three methods to use for regions:

```
– locationManager:didEnterRegion:
– locationManager:didExitRegion:
– locationManager:monitoringDidFailForRegion:withError:
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a CLLocationManagerDelegate to receive the callbacks to your app. You need to set the location item to run, and when you app goes to the background, you need to have the delegate "listen" for location updates. That can be via region monitoring -didEnterRegion or -didExitRegion. Or as simple as -didUpdateToLocation from standard location monitoring.

For more information, read [Apple's Location Awareness Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html). Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The term "forever" is conceptually wrong: Apple retains the right to kill apps at any moment. You need to reconsider the logic.

Some notes:

- it is wrong to keep localization (standard localization) always on: it consumes battery very quicky
- is better to use:

  [locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];

  This way power consumption is much less (even if precison is lower...)
- use regions: they are obeyed even if your app is was killed/ terminated. (we tested it in io5 and it works)